# Increase Size of Partition in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 500 GB hard disk on Windows 10 laptop. C drive is 350 gb while d is 150 gb. Since windows is installed in C drive i keep all my important files and study videos in d. Unfortunately d is running out of space while C drive has more than 250 gb of free space. Is it possible to shrink C drive and add more space to d?

Comment: You would have to delete the d partition in order to create a larger partition after shrinking the C partition.

Comment: Another way. Shrink C. There will be a small section in between C and D, make it E. Move data from D to E. Delete D. Extend E.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of partition manager tools available which can do this for you. Last week I used the free home edition [of Minitool Partition Wizard](https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html) for a very similar task, worked well for me.

Comment: And they can be had for free.  I've also used MPW (as well as other progs ) for the exact same situation and it's worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can shrink the volume (`C:`), then back up all the data in `D:`, then delete the `D:` at last, you can use all the unallocated space to create a new volume.

Hope this can help you!